# Are well-formed questions like "How does X work?" Ok?

Tags: discussion, not-constructive

I'm wondering if a question like that would ever be considered constructive on SO.

While I understand that one-liners like "Please tell me how Firefox works!" are terrible, can a well-phrased question be considered constructive and on-topic? Let me try to compose a sample question:

> How does C++ memory management work?
>
> I've been wondering what happens after i use `operator new`. I know
>   that the OS somehow looks for available memory of the needed size and
>   then allocates it for my application. But I fail to understand what
>   does it do under the hood! Is it the implementation of the `operator
>   new` that does it, or is it an external memory manager? A short piece of pseudo-code would be great!

For some reason I believe that questions like that would be downvoted/closed rather fast (I fail to find a good example of an actual question, sorry). However, I don't think it violates the FAQ, it covers "a software algorithm" and a "practical, answerable problems that are unique to the programming profession" (which are valid question types in the FAQ).

On the first look the question may *seem* to violate the following part of the FAQ:

> Your questions should be reasonably scoped. If you can imagine an
>   entire book that answers your question, you’re asking too much.

But if you think about it, it doesn't. A good, practical and informative answer would be a piece of pseudocode describing the main steps of "how it works", no longer than one's normal answer to a normal SO question.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1119134/how-do-malloc-and-free-work since you're pseudo-question only talks about memory allocation. What `operator new` does on top of that: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/377178/how-does-the-standard-new-operator-work-in-c

Comment: "How does C++ memory management work?" still too broad. Your sample needs a more specific title.

Comment: @Mat: It's not a duplicate of those though, they're related.

Comment: @Mat that question is just a pure example, not like I wanted to ask exactly it on SO ;)

Comment: That's the point. Such questions can be asked if they're reasonably scoped/well asked. @Madara: not exact dupes but the answers answer the example question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The main difference between "How does Firefox work" and "How does C++ memory management work", is the scope of the question.

In the case of Firefox, I would easily vote to close as either Not a real Question (overly broad), or as Not Constructive.

In the second case, we're:

1. Talking about a more specific subject
2. OP stated what he has researched, and where his understanding came to a halt.

In this case, I would happily answer the question, as well as upvote it for his well researched and well formed question. (Even if I'd rather the OP used a more specific title)

So yes, in these cases, I think that's OK. Sadly though, on most cases the questions are not well formatted nor well written.